# regex find all img tag not in for and remove

Tags: php, html, regex, image

i want remove all img tag in a string if don`t like my form but i can't it

example (i want to stay in my string) :

```
<img src="http://localhost/uploads/user1/test3.jpg" title="test" class="img-responsive img-maxheight">
<img src="http://localhost/uploads/user2/test1.jpg" alt="test" class="img-responsive img-maxheight">
<img src="http://localhost/uploads/user3/test2.jpg" class="img-responsive img-maxheight">
```

and my regex code in php is :

```
$pattern ="/<img src=\"http:\/\/localhost\/(uploads|thumbs)\/$user\/(.*?)\" (alt|title|)=\"(.*?)\" class=\"img-responsive img-maxheight\">/i";

$replacement = ' ';
$content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
```

Comment: Why use regex? ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0):

The shortest version of a possible pattern would be `/<img[^>]*>/`.
This will probably work most of the time. A bit better would be this: `/<\simg[^>]*>/`. It will work with `<  img ......>`, too.
You can insert very many corner cases to improve the pattern, but the better solution would be [not to use a regex in the first place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).
Instead, you should be parsing the html by dedicated parsers: [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: See similar form to keep and delete the rest.keep : <img src="http://localhost/uploads/user1/test3.jpg" title="test" class="img-responsive img-maxheight">
<img src="http://localhost/uploads/user2/test1.jpg" alt="test" class="img-responsive img-maxheight">
<img src="http://localhost/uploads/user3/test2.jpg" class="img-responsive img-maxheight"> other remove.

Comment: please answer my Question,do`nt ask Question?!!!!! $pattern ="/<img src=\"http:\/\/localhost\/(uploads|thumbs)\/$user\/(.*?)\" (alt|title|)=\"(.*?)\" class=\"img-responsive img-maxheight\">/i";
if not like pattern,remove from string.